# babrahams:editable-text and useraccounts users collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

Can I use babrahams:editable-text package with users collection from useraccounts. I am trying like this:

```
{{> editableText collection="users" field="username" title="Enter username"}}
```

It is not working ? Any idea why ?

Comment: Try Meteor.users since this is full collection name.

Comment: You need the Mongo collection name, not the variable name of the Meteor collection instance, so in this case it would be "users", not "Meteor.users". It's probably not working because the surrounding data context isn't set as a document from the "Meteor.users" collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Meteor.users" for your collection and then in your routes you need to set the data context:

```
Router.route('account', {
  name: 'Profile',
  data: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
  }
});
```

If you had an account route for a profile template this is how you'd make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Package author here.

You need to set the surrounding data context to be a document from the `Meteor.users` collection, but the `collection` param should be `users`, not `Meteor.users`. The code would look something like this:

```
{{#with currentUser}}
  {{> editableText collection="users" field="username" placeholder="Enter username"}}
{{/with}}
```